# How can I install SNEG Library package on Windows?

Tags: packages, physics

I want to save my time doing second quantization calculation, so I tried to install SNEG package. (http://nrgljubljana.ijs.si/sneg/)

But in the website I only founnd ways to install the package on MacOS or Linux. Is the package available to Windows users? How can I install it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a question that you should be asking the maintainer of the package.

Comment: You could just evaluate `Get["http://nrgljubljana.ijs.si/sneg/sneg.m"]` to load all the functions from this package.

Comment: Thanks you Jason! that works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Although, it seems like the question has been addressed in comments, it may be useful to clarify the subject in general. The command `Get["http://nrgljubljana.ijs.si/sneg/sneg.m"]` does not install the package, it simply loads the package into the Mathematica session from the Web. This does not allow one using it offline.

### Installation on Windows

#### Step-by-step manually

1. Download sneg-1.250.tar.gz archive from http://nrgljubljana.ijs.si/sneg/sneg-1.250.tar.gz
2. Extract files from sneg-1.250.tar.gz archive into a folder using, for example, [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html). The produced folder will contain sneg-1.250.tar archive.
3. Extract files from sneg-1.250.tar into a folder again. This time, the produced folder, say sneg-1.250, will contain files and folders of the `sneg` library.
4. Open any Mathematica notebook and evaluate `SystemOpen[FileNameJoin[{$BaseDirectory, "Applications"}]]` (if you want to install package for all users of the PC) or `SystemOpen[FileNameJoin[{$BaseDirectory, "Applications"}]]` (if you want to intall the package for only one user, i.e. youself).
5. The previous step navigates you to a standard location for all Mathematica packages. In this opened location create folder "sneg".
6. Copy content of the extracted archive with `sneg` library into the created "sneg" folder in the standard location for Mathematica packages.

**Note:** Despite this installation the documentation will not work in Mathematica 11.0+. In Mathematica 10.0+ it works in principle, but for this you need to go to "Add-ons and Packages": Help->Wolfram Documentation->Add-ons and Packages (at the very bottom of the pop-up page). There you will find "sneg documentation". By clicking on this you will invoke Mathematica Help Browser, where you can see documentation pages.

#### Automated installation

As an alternative, you can try to install `TBpack` application that contains Sneg Library as a subcontext: https://github.com/vasilsaroka/TBpack . (Sneg Library is a part of TBpack starting from v0.4.0).
In this case, an installation is simpler (it works actually for Windows/Linux/MacOS):

- In Mathematica 11.3+:

```
ResourceFunction["InstallTBpack"][]
```

- In Mathematica 10.0+:

```
CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/vasil.saroka/TBpack/Services/InstallTBpack"];
InstallTBpack[]
```

**Note:** For now Sneg Library is included into TBpack without documentation. However, as usual for any function the usage message can be invoked: *?func*.